# How to use Url.getFileFieldURL

Tags: apex, files

I have created and added an attachment using apex code. Now I need to get the download link for this. So I tried Url.getFileFieldURL. I tried with both 'Body' and 'AttachmentBody' as the second parameters. Both did not work. I am getting the error

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid parameter value \"Body\" for parameter \"fieldName\"

Please suggest how to use this method.

Comment: you can get the download link for your attachment record as: '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=YOUR_ATTACHMENT_ID'.

You can create hyperlinks and use it.

Comment: In your previous Question you asked a similar Question. How different is this one?

Comment: previous question is to explore option to download dynamically created file. This one is for understanding how to use  Url.getFileFieldURL.